# Python unittest only fails when all class tests are executed

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) class, which tests some [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) I created. The `test_init` method is passing, when I am running it alone. When I am running all tests from the class the `test_init` method is failing.

It is failing because the variables of the object `address` have values allocated, where everything should be just None.

The allocated values are the ones from the test method `test_from_dict_int`. But I have no clue, how this can happen, because `address` is just a local variable right?

If I am deleting the `set_up` method and not using the `self.address` variable, both tests are working. But I am not understanding, why its not working right now.

```
class TestAddress(TestCase):
    def set_up(self) -> None:
        self.address = None
        self.address = Address()

    def test_init(self):
        # TODO: why has address not None values when class is executed
        address = Address()
        self.assertEqual(address.first_byte, AddressRegister(None, None, None))
        self.assertEqual(address.second_byte, AddressRegister(None, None, None))
        self.assertEqual(address.third_byte, AddressRegister(None, None, None))
        self.assertEqual(address.fourth_byte, AddressRegister(None, None, None))

    def test_from_dict_int(self):
        self.set_up()
        # 0x6728, 0x958D, 0x01F0, 0x4B3C
        address_dict = {
            "first_byte": 26408,
            "second_byte": 38285,
            "third_byte": 496,
            "fourth_byte": 19260
        }
        self.address.from_dict_int(address_dict)
        self.assertEqual(self.address.first_byte, address_dict["first_byte"])
        self.assertEqual(self.address.second_byte, address_dict["second_byte"])
        self.assertEqual(self.address.third_byte, address_dict["third_byte"])
        self.assertEqual(self.address.fourth_byte, address_dict["fourth_byte"])
```

I am using the `set_up` method, because I want to write multiple tests, which all use the default class Address(). Therefore I want to use the unittest build in [setUp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) method, which generates a new blank address object, before every test.

**ADDITIONAL:**

The error is caused by my dataclass, which looks like this:

```
@dataclass
class Address:
    first_byte: AddressRegister = AddressRegister() 
    second_byte: AddressRegister = AddressRegister()
    third_byte: AddressRegister = AddressRegister()
    fourth_byte: AddressRegister = AddressRegister()

@dataclass
class AddressRegister:
    int16: int = 0
```

When I am changing it to `first_byte: AddressRegister = None` and create the object in the **post_init** like this `self.first_byte = AddressRegister()` everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are dependencies within the use of variables that manipulate your test.

- Either you ignore the set_up() method and create the variables in each test separately (remove self.address) *OR*
- you implement a tear_down() method that resets the corresponding operations from the setup (according to the connect-disconnect principle) *OR*
- you check the accesses of your variables again, because something in your tests is preserving state. Make sure to clean up, shut down or reset or disable resources which were set up for each test

Comment: A tear_down method was not solving the problem.

If I delete the `set_up()`, remove `self.address` and am only using a local `address` variable I get the same problem. The `address` variable has already some values inside.

I added a `clear()` method to `Address()` which resets all values. But if I am adding that to the test method, I am testing the `clear()` method and not the init method of `Address()`.